# jquery doesnt work inside form runat=server

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a problem with displaying chart inside form tag using runat=server clause. If I remove the clause chart works. I was also trying to use <%=container%> except of #container in jquery definition but it doesnt help. This is my code with runat clause. If u have any ideas where is the problem i would really appreciate your answer, thanks!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="chart_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebUI_Commisions.CS3500.CS3510.chart_test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
    ],
        crosshair: true
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

      }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

      }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

      }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

      }]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any js errors when using runat=server?

Comment: no, it show me blank page

Comment: Like, no markup at all?

Comment: Put jquery include outside form tag.

Comment: If you are loading jquery inside server and writing jQuery code inside server tag that can works as expected.

Comment: when I run the page with runat=server inside form tag it show me blank page without any errors

Comment: @Parth Trivedi do u mean this? if yes, it doesnt help <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        
      </div>
    </form>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

Comment: Please check my answer.Is this helpful?

Comment: form with ranat=server make post call to server for jquery and this will break your screen.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i checked it, but it doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

form with ranat=server make post call to server for jquery and this will break your screen.So try this code with jQuery out side server tag

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="chart_test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebUI_Commisions.CS3500.CS3510.chart_test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
    ],
        crosshair: true
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

      }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

      }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

      }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

      }]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: doesnt help, same effect...blank page

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. Add some text explaining what exactly is the problem and how is it resolved. Besides, your change is not likely to affect anything

Comment: As per your question runat="server" makes page break.Is this ok?

Comment: You should try ScriptManager & Update Panel.

Comment: Try this link http://www.balsamino.com/programming/20-highcharts-databinding-in-c.html

Comment: Also try http://deebujacob.blogspot.in/2013/03/auto-refresh-highcharts-graph-in.html

Comment: @ParthTrivedi thats a great example, thanks a lot parth! Finally it started to work, but the problem was with compatibility view in IE11 :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the javascript code insite the form tag. its working.

I have tried doing this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
    ],
                    crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now its also working for me, problem was with enabled compatibility view in IE11 :)